# Symfony 4 change default form name

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4

I create 2 forms not linked to any entity in the same controller.
Each form have it owns submitted button. 
I never goes to the submitted function of the second form.
I think it is because the 2 forms have same default name 'form'.
The problem is how to change the form name?
Below what I did

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $form1 = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('sn', TextType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            ])
        ->add('search', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Search'])
        ->getform();
    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {
       //Do something

    }

    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $form2->add('Agree', CheckboxType::class, [
                    'label'    => 'Agree',
                    'required' => false,
                ]);
    $form2->add('detail', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Detail']);
    $form2 = $form2->getForm();
    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {
        //Do something else
    }

    return $this->render('search/index.html.twig', [
        'form1' => $form1->createView(),
        'form2' => $form2->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated html in the browser to see what is going on?  Two forms posting to the same url is a bit unusual.  You could have them post to different controller actions.

Comment: What do you do inside your `if ($form1)` ? Do you return a response?
By the way, you haven't any constraint added to your form and any model linked to it too. It seems normal to me that your validation isn't triggered

Comment: Yes I think it was definitely a bad idea. I will merge my 2 forms in one and create several submit button.

Comment: @Mcsky: In the if($form1) I will create some data to insert in the form2 in function of the result of form1...

Comment: Yes this seems very complicated, you could think to use [form event listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) to configure your form in function of the submitted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the form name, use the createNamed() method:

```
$form1 = $this
    ->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamed('my_name', TextType::class, $task);
```

You can even suppress the name completely by setting it to an empty string.

Comment: I did it, but it seems that the issue I have is not with same form name. I still didn't go into the form2 validation after submit

Comment: You cant send two form in the same time. If you need this, ... I think you need a main form that includes both or simply another form that is aimed to save two different thing. Or something like that.